# What is a leaf entity?

Tags: ejb, entity

I am reading a book about EJB, I see the term "a leaf entity" but I am not sure what it means. As far as I can guess from the context, it is a concrete entity that can be instatiated. However, later I found in the book  that the non-leaf entity can also be concrete. Could anyone tell me the difference between the two? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether an entity is concrete or abstract is only an indirect result of whether it is a leaf or otherwise.  The differentiation is in the inheritance.

A leaf entity has no subclasses, therefore **must** be instantiable.

An intermediate entity has subclasses (and inherits from a class closer to the root entity) and **may** (or may not) be instantiable.

From [Beginning EJB 3 Application Development](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/beginning-ejb-3-ch2-134477.pdf):   <- Link to pdf download

> An abstract entity must be an intermediate class in an entity inheritance hierarchy - it may not itself be a leaf entity since it may only be instantiated through one of its subentities.  Correspondingly, all leaf entities in an entity inheritance hierarchy must be concrete, and therefore instantiable.