# What is a leaf entity in the inheritance hierarchy and what are examples of?

Tags: sql, oop, inheritance, doctrine-orm, entity

The following was provided by [Inheritance Mapping - Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) and was only modified to pertain to both STI and CTI.

> There is a general performance consideration with Single or Class
> Table Inheritance (STI or CTI): If the target-entity of a many-to-one
> or one-to-one association is a STI or CTI entity, it is preferable for
> performance reasons that it be a leaf entity in the inheritance
> hierarchy, (ie. have no subclasses). Otherwise Doctrine CANNOT create
> proxy instances of this entity and will ALWAYS load the entity
> eagerly.

In addition to the Doctrine docs, [What is a leaf entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539361/what-is-a-leaf-entity) provides a similar description, however, I still don't have a clear enough understanding, and would like to see examples.

Let's say I have entities `V8Engine`, `V6Engine`, and `Straight4Engine` which all extend `AbstractEngine`, and another entity `Automobile` where many automobiles have one engine (sorry for my fictional example and change if you think necessary).  Please describe what leaf entities are and provide an example of both where the target-entity is and is not a leaf entity.

Comment: Asking for examples is just not a good fit for stackoverflow.  I'm sure there are Doctrine specific forums out there.  Having said that, I personally don't like lazy loading and structure most of my queries to avoid it.  So the 'disadvantge' quoted in the docs is actually a positive one for me.  I also suspect that there is no single 'best' approach and it very much depends on the use case.

Comment: @Cerad  I can change the question to "What is a leaf entity in the inheritance hierarchy?" but my quoted somewhat answers that question, however, I still don't understand it.  I will change the question at risk of being closed as a duplicate, and hope you will be willing to help clarify before that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking two questions:

1. What are leaf entities?
2. What if I use an entity with (Single or Class) Table Inheritance as a target entity?

## 1. What are leaf entities?

Let say you've got these classes:

```
abstract class AbstractEngine {}
final class V6Engine extends AbstractEngine {}
class V8Engine extends AbstractEngine {}
class AudiV8Engine extends V8Engine {}
```

- AbstractEngine is an abstract entity and is therefore not a leaf.
- V6Engine is a final class. It can't have subclasses and is a leaf.
- V8Engine is not final and has a subclass (AudiV8Engine) and is not a leaf.
- AudiV8Engine is not final, but has no subclasses and is also a leaf.

Note that Doctrine entities [can't be `final`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/architecture.html#entities) so that might be a reason that they're not mentioning the word final.

## 2. What if I use (Single or Class) Table Inheritance as a target entity?

According to the docs, Doctrine cannot create proxy instances if you have a relationship with non-leaf entity. This may cause a performance penalty, but it depends on your situation how big this issue is.

In one of my projects I'm using Table Inheritance (Organisation as a base class with subclasses Customer and Supplier). In most cases the target-entity is either Customer or Supplier, but in some cases the target-entity is Organisation. It's one of the most important entities in my project and I haven't experienced performance issues.

So based on the documentation and my own experience: you can use Table Inheritance as a target entity, but if performance is very important, reconsider the usage of STI/CTI.

Comment: Thanks Stephan.  Based on your response, it appears that `Automobile` should not have a `many-to-many` relationship to `AbstractEngine`.  If so, this is a little concerning as it prevents superset/subset relationships which is my primary reason for using STI or CTI and I would otherwise just use a mapped superclass.  I expect I am missing something and if you feel so please comment.

Comment: @user1032531 I've updated my question and added my own experience with STI as a target-entity.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Glad you haven't experienced performance issues.  I don't know if there is an alternative with database integrity to inheritance for some cases.  For instance, Customer and Supplier might have a many-to-one relationship to VerticalMarket or even common Users may belong to each.

Comment: In my project (a sort of market place), a (enterprise) customer recently started to sell services to another (small business) client. And another customer asked if a user (from a supplier) could manage the account on their behalf. So I regret choosing this STI entity, but only because on hindsight their is no clear distinction between Customer and Supplier, not because performance issues.